# Bottle Version Python Web Framework

Tags: python, frameworks, web, version, bottle

Need help with bottle, I have a clean installation of Ubuntu 11.10, i'm
trying to get bottle with the next command : sudo apt-get install python-bottle, and i get the  bottle version 0.9.5-1 , that's not the last one(0.10.6-1) and does not include some features that i need.
Anybody knows why? I do not want to use easy-install or pip, help!

Comment: Why not use `pip`? Put it in a virtual env and don't worry about the system-provided version.

Comment: The answer to "why" is that the maintainers of the package in your repository only put version 0.9.5-1 there. Contact them if you're not willing to install it without using your package manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to upgrade your Ubuntu installation to [precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-bottle) (version 0.10.6) or to [quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/python-bottle) (version 0.10.11).

Older Ubuntu releases do not get new versions of packages; `python-bottle` is also not part of the [Ubuntu backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports) packages.

I strongly advise you to use a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/index.html) and install the latest bottle version in there with `pip`. Ubuntu packages are not agile enough to follow the faster release cycles of many Python packages.